# Creating an array of all folders in a directory in linux returns error

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, syntax, syntax-error

I'm new to coding and am encountering an error that I'm sure is a very simple fix. I am trying to create an array in linux using the following:

```
testarray = (/filepath/a/ /filepath/b/ /filepath/c/)
```

But I get this error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I've also tried

```
testarray = (/filepath_tofolder_where_abc_are/*/)
```

and

```
 testarray = (~/filepath_tofolder_where_abc_are/*/)
```

but I get the same error. I know there are a lot of other similar posts on this forum but I've tried their suggestions and nothing seems to work! Thanks so much for the help!

Sam

Comment: In Bash, there must not be any spaces around the `=` in an assignment.  More precisely, the whole assignment needs to be one shell "word", with at least the variable name and `=` unquoted.

Comment: Oh, I can't believe how easy that fix was! I took the spaces out around the = and it worked. I've previously only coded in R where that is acceptable. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, Bash is unusual in that way.